# Send Connector on Port 465

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp, exchange

I recently confront a problem that i think it will become a major situation on the near future.

My ISP blocked the port 25 against spamming. Now I'm forced to fix this situation on another port, so I can be able to send mails. And I tried with port 465 and no success.

Here it is how i did:

I opened exchange management shell (i use exchange 2010) and typed the following:

```
Set-SendConnector "example.com" -Port 465
```

and then when I try to:

```
telnet mail.example.com 465
```

It displays Connection Failed.

Please can someone tell me how to do exactly so I can be able to send mail on port 465. I have a valid SSL certificate installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send mail on port 465 because nobody has their mail servers configured to listen on 465. Call your ISP and fix them blocking port 25, or get a new ISP.

Being able to send mail on port 25 is critical.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you, this was the information that i need it

Answer (score 2):

What is "example.com"? It is your own domain, or a domain in the internet? Do you know exactly the purpose of send connector.

> A Send connector controls the flow
>   of outbound messages to the **receiving server**. They are configured on
>   Mailbox servers running the Transport service. Most commonly, you
>   configure a Send connector to send outbound email messages to a smart
>   host or directly to their recipient, using DNS.

The mail.example.com must be configure to accept mail from port 465, so from your mail server, you can send mail to example.com via port 465.

Otherwise, you can not do that.

Comment: example.com it represent my domain, and the thing is i can receive mails but i cannot send mails because the isp blocked it. So my question is how do i configure the exchange to be able to send mail on  another port

Answer (score 0):

These problems occur often with ISPs who try to block port 25 to reduce/prevent spammers on their networks. Most of the ISPs I delt with either provided alternative port 465 to send email on or you were forced to pay for "commercial grade" connection. Having said that some ISPs did provide port 25 for email if you had a fixed IP address.

So your solution is most likely to get a service provider for mail relay. Most of hosting companies that provide you email services will thus allow you to send emails via their system as you will be an authenticated users. They also will provide things like SMTPS and TLS for connections on various ports. Shop around. If cost too much of an issue consider using google as smart